# Align Array Plots

Tags: plotting

I have two `ArrayPlot`s that I would like to align but my "tweaking" failed yet. I would like each "row" to be aligned.

```
lista = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];
listb = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10], {1000}];

Row[{ArrayPlot[{Table[0, {Length@lista}], lista}\[Transpose], 
                Frame -> False,
                AspectRatio -> 6/1, 
                ImageSize -> {100, 700}], 
     ArrayPlot[listb\[Transpose], 
               AspectRatio -> 3.5/6, 
               ImageSize -> {1200, 700}, 
               Frame -> False]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @500 Hi 500! What are those plots?

Comment: @belisarius. Effect of a basis at first. But just cool things I find :-) Please check : http://leah.psych.nyu.edu/~laehNYU/main.html I am sure you will understand a lot of other questions ;-) I just really love "visual abstraction".

Comment: Damn! You are playing! :D ... nice work!

Comment: @belisarius, Thank You :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this particular instance, you can align the two array plots within a row by specifying each `ImageSize` to have the form `{Automatic, h}`, for some common `h`, and also making `PlotRangePadding` and `ImagePadding` both be none, like so:

```
Row[{
  ArrayPlot[List /@ lista, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 250}, 
   Frame -> False,
   PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None],
  ArrayPlot[Transpose@listb, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
   ImagePadding -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None,
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 250}, Frame -> None]}
]
```

This yields:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Simply use the options `ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}, PlotRangePadding -> 0` in both plots.   Adjust the height to your liking, 700 pixels is much too  large for my screen, so I used 300.  If you have labels/axes, also set `ImagePadding` to a non-`Automatic` value.

Comment: Can you check if it's a dupe of the above two questions I linked to? I don't have an mma to test.

Comment: At least on my machine, I still needed to set `ImagePadding` without frames or axes.

Comment: @R.M Well, it's closely related, but I wouldn't close as a dupe this time ... my question was focusing on making sure that both graphics fit tightly in their cells, while the more recent question needs `ImagePadding`, while here `PlotRangePadding` is the key.

Comment: @Pillsy On WinXP it works fine without an explicit `ImagePadding` (there's a margin but they're the same for the two figures), but yes, I can imagine that it is fragile without that.

Comment: +1 It is what I was going to answer, and looks good enogh in Mma 8.0.0 Win Xp